# Problem with the Fisher information matrix in case of N measurements of two observables

Tags: forecasting, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, fisher-information, cramer-rao

Let consider two observables, $x$ and $y$. Suppose that $y$ depends on the independent variable $x$ through the model $m(x; \boldsymbol{\theta})$, where $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is a vector of model parameters.
I want to estimate the Cramer-Rao bound of one of these parameters, for forecasting purposes. To this aim, I have to calculate the Fisher information matrix and inverse it.
I should be able to compute it before doing any experiments.

Let assume that

1. Measurements of $\{x;y\}$ are uncorrelated each other.
2. Measurements of the independent variable $x$ have no uncertainty.
3. Measurements of $y$ are Gaussian distributed, with fixed variance $\sigma^2$ (it's the uncertainty of each measurement of $y$).
4. The likelihood is Gaussian, i.e.: $L(\boldsymbol{\theta};\{x,y\}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|2 \pi C|}} e^{-\dfrac{1}{2} \left[y - m(x; \boldsymbol{\theta})\right]^{T} C^{-1} \left[y - m(x; \boldsymbol{\theta})\right]}$, where $C$ is the covariance matrix of the data.
5. $C$ does not depend on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$.

With these assumptions, the covariance matrix of the data is diagonal ($C = \dfrac{\mathbb{1}}{\sigma^2}$) and thus the elements of the Fisher information matrix are:

\begin{equation}
F_{\alpha \beta} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i}^{N} \dfrac{\partial m(x_i; \boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\theta_\alpha} \dfrac{\partial m(x_i; \boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\theta_\beta} \;,
\end{equation}

where $N$ is the number of measurements.

**Questions:**

1. If so far it is correct, knowing $F$ implies knowing the measurements of $x_i$ *a priori* of the experiment; how can this be possible?
2. Can $F$ be computed and inverted analytically, in case of $N=1000$ measurements for example?
3. Even in case of $N = 1$, $F$ always has null determinant.
   In fact, $F$ is always of the type:
   \begin{pmatrix}
   a^2 & ab\\
   ba & b^2
   \end{pmatrix}
   How to deal with it?

**Practical example:**

My observables $\{x;y\}$ are respectively time and position $\{t;s\}$. The model is $m(t; \delta, \phi, \omega, G) = A e^{-\delta t} \cos(\phi - \sqrt{\omega^2 - \delta^2}t) + \dfrac{G}{\omega}$.

- In the case of $N=1$, $F$ has a null determinant.
- In the case of
  $N>1$, each element of $F$ is a sum over the values of $t$. The
  matrix cannot be computed without knowing the array of the
  measurements of $t$. Therefore, if you know the values of $t$, is the computation of the matrix can be done only numerically, do you agree?

At this point I can see only one possible way out:
since I need to calculate the Cramer-rao bound of $G$, I could first marginalize over all the parameters; deleting all the columns and rows of $F$ related to the other parameters should do the trick (or this procedure should be applied to the inverse of F? I am not sure about this). As a result the reduced Fisher matrix is 1x1, that is trivially invertible. Does it make sense?

Any suggestion or example would be highly appreciated, if I'm missing something.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You say "model parameters $\theta$ are Gaussian distributed". Is this a Bayesian problem? The Cramer Rao bound applies to (unbiased) estimators, and a Bayes estimate requires formulation of a prior - note it's very hard to get a Bayes estimator that's unbiased.

Comment: @AdamO thank you for your comment. I meant "estimators of the model parameters are Gaussian distributed" and I'm assuming a uninformative prior. Now is the problem clearer? Thank you.